# I want to find the strings with the placeholders from a given string in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex

I have a string as below

```
string = "my name is [name] and Birtday is [birthday]"
```

I want to get all the words inside the placeholders into an array. The following shows the array.

```
array = [ "name", "birthday" ]
```

I have the following code.

```
array = sting.match(/[^[\]]+(?=])/g)
```

But This also returns the below text as two arrays.

```
string = "[name]month]"
array = ["name", "month"] this should be array = ["name"]
```

Comment: Use `/\[([^\][]*)]/g` and grab Group 1.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew this copy text including square brackets. "[text]"

Comment: I said "grab Group 1", see [the famous JS regex thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/432493/how-do-you-access-the-matched-groups-in-a-javascript-regular-expression).